# MongoDB error message

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run MongoDB in my terminal, and it gives me this message:

> MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10
>   connecting to: test
>   2016-10-10T17:22:31.427+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @/Users//.mongorc.js:5:30
>
> The ".mongorc.js" file located in your home folder could not be executed"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error in you `.mongorc.js` file. This file is executed before starting mongo shell, and generally used for customizing the shell, using aliases, etc.

Do the following, open `~/.mongorc.js` file, check for any syntax error and correct it.
You can also omit running .mongorc.js file by adding `--norc` flag: `mongo --norc`.

*edit:* I leave a link for more info about mongorc.js, [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#mongorc-js-file).